# Unknown attribute when linking two models together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, relationship

Brief overview of my app.

It's quite basic in that the User first of all creates a set A client on one page and then uses another to create and assign jobs to the user.

My Client model and view are working as expected but im unable to link my jobs model.

Here is my jobs model.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end
```

Here is also my clients controller.

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @jobs = Job.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml { render :xml => @job }
    end
  end

  def new
    @jobs = Job.new 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml { render :xml => @job }
    end
  end

  def create
    @jobs = Job.new(params[:job])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @jobs.save
        format.html { redirect_to @jobs, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @jobs, status: :created, location: @jobs }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @jobs.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @jobs = Job.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @jobs }
    end
  end
end
```

In my form I have two fields. One for the job name and another which is a drop down on all the clients listed in the database.

When  fill this out however and I press save im getting the following error.

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in JobsController#create

**unknown attribute: client_id**

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:22:in `new'
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:22:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"0ZVYpM9vTgY+BI55Y9yJDwCJwrwSgGL9xjHq8dz5OBE=",
 "job"=>{"name"=>"Sample Monthly",
 "client_id"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Save Job"}
```

I have a junction table setup called `clients_jobs` also..

```
class AddClientsJobsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :clients_jobs, :id => false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :job, :client
      t.integer :client_id
      t.integer :job_id
  end
end

  def down
    drop_table :clients_jobs
  end
end
```

I assume I need to declare `client_id`

somewhere but this is my first Rails app and im not sure where.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here's my Job's form.

```
<%= simple_form_for :job do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= select("job", "client_id", Client.all.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'None'})%>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you add the code for your jobs form also?

Comment: Edited the first post with the form code.

Answer (score 0):

Your model states that job - client is a habtm association, but your form implements as if job belongs to (one) client. If indeed your intention is to be able to assign a job to multiple clients, your for should look something like:

```
<%= collection_select(:job, :client_ids, Client.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => 'None'}, { :multiple => true }) %>
```

note plural 'client_ids' and allowing multiple in the input.

If a job belongs to only one user, you should not use has_and_belongs_to_many :clients.

Comment: A client can have many jobs but yes, a unique job can only belong to one client With that text im still recieving `unknown attribute: client_id`